# time.sleep(1) error -- python on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, time, raspberry-pi, sleep

I have:

```
time.sleep(1)
```

in my python twice.
However on the second time the script crashes saying:

```python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ON-BOOT.py", line 36, in <module>
    time.sleep(1)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'sleep'
```

Idk whats wrong with it.

Here is the full script (it runs at boot on my Raspberry Pi)

```python
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket
import os
import smtplib
import time
import RPi.GPIO as gpio
print "ON-BOOT running..."
time.sleep(1)
gpio.setmode(gpio.BOARD)
gpio.setup(7,gpio.IN)
bi = 0
time = 0
selectAction = "false"
os.system("omxplayer -o hdmi /var/www/siren1.mp3")
gw = os.popen("ip -4 route show default").read().split()
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect((gw[2], 0))
ipaddr = s.getsockname()[0]
gateway = gw[2]
host = socket.gethostname()
print ("IP:", ipaddr, " GW:", gateway, " Host:", host)
fromaddr = 'billyg270@example.com'
toaddrs  = 'billyg270@example.com'
msg = "ROBO pie active on port: " + ipaddr
username = 'billyg270@example.com'
password = '**MY PASSWORD**'
server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username,password)
server.sendmail(fromaddr, toaddrs, msg)
server.quit()
os.system ("espeak -ven+f3 -k5 -s150 'ROBO pie active on port " + ipaddr + "'")
print msg
time.sleep(1)
os.system ("espeak -ven+f3 -k5 -s150 'You now have 5 seconds to press the button if you wish to launch, test1'")
selectAction = "true"
while selectAction == "true":
  print "time: " + str(time)
  print "selectAction: " + selectAction
  time.sleep(0.1)
  time += 1
  print "bi: " + str(bi)
  if(time < 50):
    if (gpio.input(buttonPin)):
      #button pressed
      bi += 1
  if(time > 50):
    os.system ("espeak -ven+f3 -k5 -s150 'You can no longer press the button'")
    selectAction = "false"
    if(bi > 0):
      os.system ("espeak -ven+f3 -k5 -s150 'You have selected to launch, test1'")
      os.system("cd /var/www")
      gpio.cleanup()
      os.system("sudo python test1.py")
gpio.cleanup()
```

Comment: When you define `time = 0`, you're overwriting the definition of the `time` module from which you call `time.sleep`. You'll need to name your variable something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Line 12 writes over the time module:

```
time = 0
```

And when you call `time.sleep()` the next time, you actually call `1.sleep(1)` or something like that.

You have several refactoring options:

- `from time import sleep`
- `import time as time_module` (not too pretty imo)
- Or rename your variable, which is the best option I think.

Comment: Easy mistake to make :) [Pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) might have caught it for you.